# How to extend `CSSProperties` in react project

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am from the `javascript` world and am new to `typescript`. I have a react project written in `typescript`. I declare an inline style but got the below warning when I use it in a react component:

```
Type '{ color: string; fontSize: string; fontWeight: number; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties'.
```

Below is the code for the style declaration.

```
const styles = {
    promAlert: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column'
    }
};
```

below is the code who uses it. And the warning comes out with this line `<div style={styles.promAlert}>`.

```
<div style={styles.promAlert}>
    {alert.substring('promotions.'.length)}
</div>
```

I have searched that the this may be caused by `CSSProperties` defined in react. I may need to extend this class and add more attributes on it. I wonder how I can do that in my project.

Another question is why `CSSProperties` doesn't include all supported css keys.

Comment: Usually this error comes when a child component provides styles of different type to a parent component

Comment: Each `dom` should have its own styles and why it needs to be constrained by its parent component?

Comment: Sorry, actually i meant the reverse. When we provide a `style` props from parent to child, and the child has specified a `type` for that prop, when they dont match, such an error is shown.

Comment: Alright, this makes sense but my case is that the child component is `div` which is a standard html dom. How does it enforce style keys?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

TypeScript expects specific types `"flex"` and `"column"`, but without any additional work, it receives `string` for both, which is too wide and non-descript. You can see the same error happen here:

```
declare const value: string
const a: "a" = value // errors, `string` can't be assigned to the more specific `"a"`
```

There are a few solutions here. I think the most elegant one is `as const`, so it'll treat your object values as their specific literal types. Also make sure your TS version is up to date to use this.

```
const styles = {
    promAlert: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
    },
} as const
```

Alternatively, you can declare your style objects separately and have them typechecked by the `CSSProperties` interface. This gives autocomplete on each property, but this can't (easily) be done as a single full object.

```
const promptAlert: React.CSSProperties = {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column'
}

// you can re-assign all of your styles into a single object if you want,
// but I think it would be easier to access `promptAlert` directly at this point
const styles = {
  promptAlert,
}
```

Other less ideal solutions:

- `{ [key: string]: React.CSSProperties }`: this doesn't perform type checking on the name of each style, so you can do `styles.abcdef` without any error
- Casting each style `as React.CSSProperties`: this doesn't catch errors in the styles themselves, e.g. you could typo `display: "fleex"`

Answer (score 12):

Defining `styles` type as shown below will preserve type check on your all CSS classes and their properties:

```
const styles: { [key: string]: React.CSSProperties } = {
    promAlert: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column'
    }
};
```

Comment: A much better solution then accepted one. It will avoid writing cast multiple types in the object.

Comment: Came back and updated my answer with better solutions and explanations 

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
const styles = {
    promAlert: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column'
    }
};
```

To

```
const styles = {
    promAlert: {
        display: 'flex' as 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column' as 'column'
    }
};
```

This tells TypeScript that these values are [literals](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/literal-types.html).

Comment: I just tried this approach but it doesn't have any effects on my code. I still see the warning.